# Recharging the php script

Tags: php, html

I have written a php page and script, but I have a problem reloading the php script - my page draws a link from the database and inserts it into the  element, but only once per page reload.
What to do to get a link random every time you click on ?

It's html and php code:

```html
<?php
$DEFAULT_LINK = "default.html";
// connect to DB
require_once "connect.php";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

$sql = "SELECT link FROM pages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result !== false)
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
else
 $row = false;

if ($row && isset($row["link"]))
  $RANDOM_LINK = $row["link"];
else
  $RANDOM_LINK = $DEFAULT_LINK;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
   <title>Random it</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
   <header></header>
   <div class="random">
    <a href="<?php echo $RANDOM_LINK; ?>" target="_blank">Random</a>
   </div>
  <footer></footer>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i don't get it. what you are looking for ? your code should give you random link each time. and i think it's working fine.

Comment: Yes, it works ok, but i want get random link each time, when I click <a>, but my script random only when i refresh page

Comment: if you want random link each time after link clicked without page refreshing you should use Javascript. or using php redirect page.

Comment: Ok, i'll try it

Comment: You'll need to use an ajax function to send a request and receive a new link as the response - this will happen without the page reloading

Answer (score 0):

In the `<a>` element add a `onclick="javascript:document.location.reload();"`. That reloads the page and regenerates the link. Otherwise you'd have to use DOM and more JavaScript.